# SQL Case Expression Evaluating Same Column Twice

Tags: sql, case

I am trying assign a code depending on courses students take. The problem comes when students take two courses. In this case, they should be assigned a code and only one record should be returned for them, not two. I explain what the results should look like below.

```
--Create table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses](
    [TermCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StudentID] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [CourseCode] [varchar](6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Insert Records:
Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '123456789', '100001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '234567890', '400001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '345678901', 'BH0001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '456789012', 'BH0002');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '567890123', '100001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '567890123', 'BH0001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '678901234', '400001');

Insert into Courses (TermCode, StudentID, CourseCode)
values ('20211', '678901234', 'BH0002');
```

-- What I have so far:

```
select  StudentID,
    case 
        when CourseCode = '100001' then 'AAN1'
        when CourseCode = '400001' then 'AAN4'
        when CourseCode = 'BH0001' then 'BABH'
        when CourseCode = 'BH0002' then 'BPBH'
        when (CourseCode = '100001' and CourseCode = 'BH0001') then 'BH01'
        when (CourseCode = '400001' and CourseCode = 'BH0002') then 'BH04'
end as CustomCode
from Courses
```

-- Results I'm getting:

```
| StudentID | CustomCode |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 123456789 | AAN1       |
| 234567890 | AAN4       |
| 345678901 | BABH       |
| 456789012 | BPBH       |
| 567890123 | AAN1       |
| 567890123 | BABH       |
| 678901234 | AAN4       |
| 678901234 | BPBH       |
```

Results that I need:

```
| StudentID | CustomCode |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 123456789 | AAN1       |
| 234567890 | AAN4       |
| 345678901 | BABH       |
| 456789012 | BPBH       |
| 567890123 | BH01       |
| 678901234 | BH04       |
```

The problem with this is that it evaluates the single courses just fine. The lines where it is checking for two courses isn't working. StudentID 567890123 and 678901234 should return one record, not two. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your `case` statement operates within a **single row**.  So it's impossible to have `CourseCode` that equals two different values at the same time.

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, your suggestion worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You need aggregation if you want one row per student.  How about this?

```
select StudentID,
       (case when min(CourseCode) = max(CourseCode) and min(CourseCode) = '100001'
             then 'AAN1'
             when min(CourseCode) = max(CourseCode) and min(CourseCode) = '400001'
             then 'AAN4'
             when min(CourseCode) = max(CourseCode) and min(CourseCode) = 'BH0001'
             then 'BABH'
             when min(CourseCode) = max(CourseCode) and min(CourseCode) = 'BH0002'
             then 'BPBH'
             when min(CourseCode) = '100001' and max(CourseCode) = 'BH0001')
             then 'BH01'
             when min(CourseCode) = '400001' and max(CourseCode) = 'BH0002')
             then 'BH04'
        end) as CustomCode
from Courses
group by StudentID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simplest solution: SQL is reading in order so put the most restrictive statements first:

```
select  StudentID,
    case 
        when (CourseCode = '100001' and CourseCode = 'BH0001') then 'BH01'
        when (CourseCode = '400001' and CourseCode = 'BH0002') then 'BH04'
        when CourseCode = '100001' then 'AAN1'
        when CourseCode = '400001' then 'AAN4'
        when CourseCode = 'BH0001' then 'BABH'
        when CourseCode = 'BH0002' then 'BPBH'
end as CustomCode
from Courses
```